# Swift - Receive all types of closures and cast to objc_block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to create a function that can receive a swift closure of any type (both closures that receive 0 parameters and closures that receive 1 or more parameters) and create an objc_block out of it.


This problem is divided to two major questions:
1) How do I properly declare a function that receives all possible closure types? I'm already using functions that receive unknown types such as this:

```
func myFunc<T>(param: T) {}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to apply that to closures, considering any number of input params are possible for the input closure.


2)  The only way I found to create an objc_block out of a swift closure is to know the actual closure type, for example:

```
var objCBlock: @objc_block ()->() = {()->() in println("closure")}
```

This is a problem since I don't know the type of the input closure.


Any ideas? Is that even possible?

Comment: If you don't know the closure type, how can you call it?

Comment: What is your actual goal? What would you want that function to do?

Comment: @Sulthan Well, I don't need to call it. I'm working with JavaScriptCore, and I'm trying to create a function that will create JSValues out of these blocks, so i can pass them to the javascript context for callbacks. Since i know my javascript side as well, I'll know which blocks to give my JS functions

Comment: @Tim Bodeit well, whenever i want to pass a swift closure to the javascript context, i need to create an objc block and than a jsvalue. I'm trying to create a general function like that so i can call it with a swift closure, inline, whenever I'm calling functions in my javascript context.

Comment: Do you know any more details about the Swift closure you're getting in? (Number and Types of parameters or return type)
Whats the exact signature of the method you're calling to pass functions to that context

Comment: All the closures return Void. As for parameters, most of them will get 1 String/JSON object, some 2 or more strings, and some will get no parameters at all. It's very individual, as the different JS function I need to callback from return all kinds of values and tuples.

Comment: And as for the signature, I'm using JSValue's callWithArguments to call functions on the JS side. I'm creating JSValue objects from the swift closures I want as callbacks, and I'm adding them as arguments when I call callWithArguments.